# Counting jobs for each tech per day

Tags: excel

[image]
I have a spreadsheet like this, I would like to create the field as shown below showing "Total jobs per day" which calculated the Tech name and the date where they both occur.

```
Tech        Total jobs on day
James   28-Aug  4
Bob     29-Aug  1
James   28-Aug  4
Bob     28-Aug  1
James   28-Aug  4
Aaron   30-Aug  2
Claire  29-Aug  1
Claire  30-Aug  1
James   28-Aug  4
Aaron   30-Aug  2
```

Found the answer in programming not on excel though

Comment: what do you mean with `Found the answer in programming not on excel though`? Do you need VBA code?

Answer (score 1):

Try insert->pivot table, next choose column name with checkboxes you want to. This way you can easy make group and sum data

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SUMIFS()` formula here like so:
`=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A1,B:B,B1)`
You can either fill the entire column D with this dragged down, meaning that it counts the total jobs for that person on that date in the whole table on that row.

Alternatively you can swap out the cell references to static values and use headers like so:

```
a   28/08/2019  1
b   28/08/2019  2
a   26/08/2019  3
a   28/08/2019  4
b   29/08/2019  5
b   28/08/2019  6

A on 28/08/2019: 5
B on 28/08/2019: 8
Etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

**Code:**

`=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,A2,$B$2:$B$11,B2)`

**Results:**

[image]